# My app built with py2app crashes immediately

Tags: python, macos, py2app

When I try to build my py2app application, the build seems to go fine. But when I run it, an error pops up with no message. It lets me look at the console or terminate. The console shows nothing. I'm pretty new to Macs, so I don't know what's going on. I'll share with you what I have, and maybe someone can tell me what's up with my setup.

My project is set up like so:

```
project_name
|-- src
    |-- my_package
        |-- __main__.py
        |-- ui.py
        |-- other python files
|-- pipfile
|-- setup.py
```

The `__main__.py` simply contains the following:

```
from my_package.ui import start
start()
```

pipfile contains:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
pandas = "*"
xlrd = "*"
openpyxl = "*"
py2app = "*"
```

and setup.py contains:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name= 'My Package',
    app= ['src/my_package/__main__.py'],
    options= {'py2app': {'argv_emulation': True}},
    setup_requires= ['py2app', 'pandas', 'xlrd', 'openpyxl'],
)
```

And I run py2app with just `python setup.py py2app`

Comment: python wasn't created to build executable and programs like `py2app` , `pyinstaller` may have problem to find all needed Python modules and C/C++ libraries. If you would use `pyinstaller` then you could check its web page: `when things goes wrong` or `advanced`

Comment: @furas All the modules and libraries are installed. I was able to run the code with normal python running. And I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me about `pyinstaller`

Comment: when you runs with normal python then it has all paths to all needed module. When you runs in executabe then it doesn't use normal python in system and it may not have paths to modules. And it means not only python modules but also C/C++ libraries. For example when you build code with `tkinter` then you have to add `tcl.exe` `tk.exe`. And when you build code with `PuQt` then you may have to add libraries from Qt (C/C++). And `panda` may need `numpy` which may use `C/C++` libraries for math calculations (ie. LAPack, BLAS)

Comment: And I mentioned `pyinstaller` because it has web page where it tries to explain how to resolve some common problems with not working executables.

Comment: @furas Okay  when you say "add" `tcl.exe` and `tk.exe`, what do you mean?

Comment: `tkinter` is only wrapper on language `tcl` with its graphic module `tl`. `tkinter` converts `Python` code to `tcl` code and it runs it with `tcl.exe` (on Mac it may have name `tcl.app` or other). And you have to find this program and add to your project - add to config file.

Comment: @fumras Do you mean the "setup_requires" in setup.py?

Comment: yes, it should be in `setup_requires`. There could be also other variables for tkinter. But first you should check if problem makes `tkinter` or other module. You could start with empty tkinter window and convert it with py2app. if it will work then you should try to add other module, ext. If all modules will work then problem can be something different. You load other files and they may need correct path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but after a long time of searching I found the solution.

For me, trying to set the same as you, only remove `{'argv_emulation': True}`, with `no "options"` in your case:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name= 'My Package',
    app= ['src/my_package/__main__.py'],
    setup_requires= ['py2app', 'pandas', 'xlrd', 'openpyxl'],
)
```

It's Work for me:  [Here](https://prnt.sc/h06K5rzDbOV0)!